# How to properly handle Task Exception

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I am trying to figure out how to properly handle some exceptions in a Task:

**Calling Method:**

```
Task<Branch3GInfo> getActive3GRoutersTask = 
    Task.Run(
        () => CAS.Service.GetBranch3GInformationAsync(3)
    );

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(discoverRouterExtendedInfoTask, getActive3GRoutersTask);
}
catch(AggregateException aggEx)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Some problems occured on GetNodesInCriticalCondition(): \n");
    foreach (var ex in aggEx.InnerExceptions)
    {
        sb.Append(ex.Message);
    }

    Trace.TraceError(sb.ToString());
}

var branch3gInfo = getActive3GRoutersTask.Result;
```

`var branch3gInfo = getActive3GRoutersTask.Result;` throws a `System.Aggregate Exception`.

**Called method:**

```
public async Task<Branch3GInfo> GetBranch3GInformationAsync(int searchDepth)
{
    var branch3gInfo = await GetBranch3GInterfacesAsync();

    var activeRoutersExtInfos = new List<CasApiRouterModelExtendedInfo>();
    foreach (var netInterface in branch3gInfo.Branch3GActiveInterfaces)
    {
        try
        {
            var task = GetRouterExtendedInfoFromInterfaceAsync(netInterface, searchDepth);
            var result = await task;

            if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && result != null)
            {
                activeRoutersExtInfos.Add(result);
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Error occured trying to get info about Active 3G Router " + netInterface.ModelName + ".");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Error occured trying to get info about Active 3G Router " + netInterface.ModelName +
                ": \n" + ex.Message);
        }

    }

    return new Branch3GInfo()
    {
        Branch3GActiveInterfaces = branch3gInfo.Branch3GActiveInterfaces,
        Branch3GCapableInterfaces = branch3gInfo.Branch3GCapableInterfaces,
        Branch3GActiveRouters = activeRoutersExtInfos.ToArray()
    };
}
```

From my code, I am making the assumption that `GetBranch3GInformationAsync()` should be either executing the `else` clause which doesn't add the result to `activeRoutersExtInfos`, OR, it should be catching the exception.  Why is it that the calling method throws a `System.AggregateException` if I am handling this in `GetBranch3GInformationAsync()`?

How do I go about fixing this so that any call to `GetRouterExtendedInfoFromInterfaceAsync()` that fails due to an exception is ignored, and so that it doesn't break my code?

UPDATE:
Stack trace for the `InnerException` in `System.AggregateException` ("The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.")

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at CASpectrumApi.CasApiRestCall.<ExecuteAsync>d__38.MoveNext() in C:\src\CASpectrumApi\src\CASpectrumApi\Queries\CasApiRestCall.cs:line 294
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at CASpectrumApi.Managers.CasApiServiceManager.<RenderAndExecuteRestCallAsync>d__103.MoveNext() in C:\src\CASpectrumApi\src\CASpectrumApi\Managers\CasApiServiceManager.cs:line 2516
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at CASpectrumApi.Managers.CasApiServiceManager.<QueryModelsFilterByAttributeNotDeviceOnlyAsync>d__51.MoveNext() in C:\src\CASpectrumApi\src\CASpectrumApi\Managers\CasApiServiceManager.cs:line 1196
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at CASpectrumApi.Managers.CasApiServiceManager.<GetBranch3GInterfacesAsync>d__34.MoveNext() in C:\src\CASpectrumApi\src\CASpectrumApi\Managers\CasApiServiceManager.cs:line 442
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at CASpectrumApi.Managers.CasApiServiceManager.<GetBranch3GInformationAsync>d__26.MoveNext() in C:\src\CASpectrumApi\src\CASpectrumApi\Managers\CasApiServiceManager.cs:line 246
```

Comment: What's the exception details for the `AggregateException` you're seeing?

Comment: Your method isn't handling all the exceptions. Lets say `branch3gInfo` is null. You'll get NRE, which is then propagated to the calling method. Refer the `AggregateException.InnerExceptions` property for more detail.

Comment: @StephenCleary It contains one InnerException, which states that an HTTP call returned an HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error).  I have updated the question the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see from your call stack:

```
at CASpectrumApi.Managers.CasApiServiceManager.<GetBranch3GInterfacesAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
```

that it is the call to `GetBranch3GInterfacesAsync` that is failing, not the call to `GetRouterExtendedInfoFromInterfaceAsync`. `GetBranch3GInterfacesAsync` is called outside the `try` block, so naturally the exception will propagate.

Comment: Shouldn't the try/catch in the calling method
`try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(discoverRouterExtendedInfoTask, getActive3GRoutersTask);
            }` 

take care of catching the exception?

Comment: @blgrnboy: It will be raised there, and it will be re-raised if you call `getActive3GRoutersTask.Result`.